# Installing .NET 4.0 on Windows Server 2003 SP2

Tags: .net, .net-4.0, windows-xp, installation

I live in the world of Dark Matter developers where we still have to support mission-critical applications running on Windows Server 2003, SP2, 32 bit.  At least I have the ability to upgrade to .net 4.0 on this machine.  However, when I run the .net 4.0 full installer, I get the error:

```
Final Result: Installation failed with error code: (0x800B0100), "No signature was present in the subject."
```

Does anyone know how to get this to work?  I have done it on a similar machine, but that was about a year ago.

Comment: The registry on that machine is broken.  Follow the troubleshooters you find when you google "0x800b0100".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ok, I got it.  I had a bad installer, a lightweight one that needed to download components.  When I got the right full package, and ran as Admin, then it installed just fine. The machine I was on did not allow downloads from Microsoft.

Here's the package I used:

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17718